# Bathroom Sink Plumbing

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

I installed a new countertop and sink in my 20 yr old home. The existing sink drain pipe is 1 1/2 and it appears to be a Street fitting but with an edge on it to retain a threaded ring.

[image]
[image]

I have tried a number of fittings from Home Depot but no luck mating to this existing pipe. This Threaded trap didn’t mate with the metal threaded ring.

[image]

Does anyone know what I should be looking for or should I cut it off and go with a regular Street fitting and glued Ptrap?  Thanks

Comment: Which particular fittings did you try?

Comment: Personally, I'd be tempted to use a shielded Fernco and whatever fitting was close enough.

Comment: What does the old fitting look like which attached to that piece?